# How to add dashed border on View's frame not on bounds [Swift]

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to add a dashed border on View which will  always be on the view's frame not on it's bound .

My code :

```
func addDashedBorder() {

    let color = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let frameSize = self.bounds.size
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x:0 , y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)

    shapeLayer.frame = shapeRect
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height/2)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,3]
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.frame, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath

    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

**Result**
[image]

I don't want to rotate the Border on View if we rotate the view . 
it should indicate how much space its is taking on view .

**Expectation**

[image]

Comment: You outer dashed view should have the height and width equal to the inner views diagonal √2 * width of the arrow view. Then it's just a matter of animating the arrow view. P.S - you first image will have a larger padding between the arrows and the border.

Comment: padding is ok , my task is to show , what us the frame of innner view .  view can be Square or rectangular

Comment: The outer view will always be a square having the its side length and the longest diagonal of the inner view.

Comment: Mr. Dhiru this is the image in centre with arrows?

Comment: Yes that is Image , that can be anything .

Comment: That can be anything or image why dont you talk to your designer about rotating the image and then you stick into the UIImage rather than trying at your end.

Comment: My task is not that @HarjotSingh , it is a ImageView  is has Rotation Gesture enabled , user can rotate and drag to any place . it is not a static image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take two view i.e inner and outer view. Inner view (rotation view) should be in the subview of outer view. The frame must be same for both views. Use the following line of code -

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewOuter: UIView! //static outer view
@IBOutlet weak var viewInner: UIView! // View that will be use for rotation

func addDashedBorder() {

    let color = UIColor.red.cgColor
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let frameSize = viewInner.bounds.size
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x:0 , y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)
    shapeLayer.frame = shapeRect
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height/2)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,3]
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: viewInner.frame, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
    self.viewOuter.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

}
```